# Can LSTM be used for non time series data?

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, lstm

I have a dataset -

[image]

This is a TOR network traffic dataset with labels added as TOR/ Non TOR.

I want to run an LSTM on it and classify it as Tor/Non Tor. Is that possible since this is not a time series data?

Comment: LSTMs are for sequences. Is this a sequence or are they independent data points?

Comment: @noe each row represents a network packet..hence not sure If its a sequence..hence I asked

Comment: You need to ask yourself if your data is represented as a sequence, where the input values at a given point of the sequence are influenced by the values of the previous points. This is the basic idea of a recurrent neural network, of which LSTM is a particular iteration.

Answer (score 0):

If the packets are sorted in time and you think there might be some correlation between packets that help identify TOR/nonTOR, then you may try an LSTM.

I suggest you add a new column with the delta time since the previous packet.